Unable to open Azure Devops page after I switched to default directory
I’m Sudarshan Reddy, a Data Engineer at Oracle in India. Last week, I signed up for a free trial plan on Azure to improve my skills with their products.
I accessed Azure DevOps using the same account, but when I switched to the default directory, the page opened with the following link and only displays a blank screen (see attached picture). I’ve also cleared my browser’s cache and cookies. Could you please assist me? I need to practice CI/CD for ADF pipelines.
https://aexprodeus21.vsaex.visualstudio.com/_public/_MsalRedirect#code=0.AcYAYFs8yyc7qECbp7zBInoR5ayEm0khE39CqhcmfKaXV5jGAGc.AgABBAIAAAApTwJmzXqdR4BN2miheQMYAgDs_wUA9P8QWUk1VrBVxNrzpnyhcpSB67ehDEg0Vd41kn_s780kWoFw-DPHJhhe0vOUdqg7LRtqzOm9E6kfDujsR8GCBnyvCcMlD8-B5MFAooGfWU0ofITkPOR3shZxA8mkDtWeAazlFgTDmviUYyR1u31CPR2hMJ0_OnUd2bP-6NVBKNmY5OwQh4cAUNhJkYVil1mT13XrILAUeYY8RogG2WR1QcE6njzXuTNs3desg9v64W0oE7a1_FF8VYqkvBSfB7dpTdhC3AcONEp1xs5j_4rpOu_KI507u6wAlyIUUDrRKtd4q7lDqhzxm2IRdbeNADvnK0zzgKnqKKawsFiKfLYdH_dNsAHz75RPbAhYWHWfRAdyzuQyOuat3StutKX8eeRdCDeVF6F1e3zjTr7DJa-mhdfduNT-OgKnOo7N5gyPV7uc1brvpH29hFdWzdH9e02XaRhnM94PFAxPmddZQQWZbwgqrqgqn3p4j9kmwE5wdatWdX4MBAswBWwMj6iXpx2MKLS5XzkZB0EJ_GkwuJCiNbRZTm1E2U5gUg_l2tqXoZwaq96Rgsyo3l_h0LTIXUegTriIdJV-a8iG3u28wcN3frkvBV1b8Dupv4AnZoQ-WpSV4MtPHB7H6PD_Z5murVW2eQxScJoMk0zmRkoV64EP51uUAKUjdNYhm5M8RF0Fc3TBf9wLrux-XyunHhv3AEkRK-NNC8JYhnhFBIrbecvQVPJhf3dpMgCNSKS0YCo6e9PGgZ4F_8Wr0h4yuZzYW5onsqZgDHnlRLFsMhKB3HSbQCwq8jVsa6W7KnYKvCWpp9uZrKkmC6DWgptKyX7hop6CCXjmP10fNnnCWbxzraRutoeHP-h2KaWN6s-j0M16D01hRuQXBDkJf-WxMyOY_Llmnb8MQb0KgndmYB3SHksehlQ9ghEI6queK9CrqQSN6-zVj6iWolrk7yQa38L5zKq-Pnmf3O7P--EWvl9Is07-GInewbPDcefvTelHpXE6pdwju1lBMwXgFRnY-Kgr7hmbMlIDa21_y1ebX_SdCg5eHJX8qCLzIkYyYV42JloE5fB190447nYnt_h7rJ3h02IcfmuV_QGwfdd2JOAPYH4RV3buWQMl5iUYpWw5AB-BEg-aY1AmG63cGrVqgDk8-CMHDNWT1tPsnc3KCySy1K-L_GFknmEbFEwtE-MReAE-FKtQ1TRFUpp_gM9M58Z9KooV8XzLZinyMOw-orVKXoLOuVdrH4_N1or6wDxVuccE_gQtLwT4gdx61wDfe0iXiOBXcir4mT8SWQdoZvnB7dD054MvlxrRh1ja2wBbomoIO3qpGIY84Tkb7N93yinFgagKUcYe2ZvXtmkyjUyv5WAy_Y2uQBnpA8h7QLvcuI0U&client_info=eyJ1aWQiOiIwMDAwMDAwMC0wMDAwLTAwMDAtMGU4MS1hNzFkMGU5ZDVjMWEiLCJ1dGlkIjoiOTE4ODA0MGQtNmM2Ny00YzViLWIxMTItMzZhMzA0YjY2ZGFkIn0&state=eyJpZCI6IjAxOTExMzc1LTAyZjYtNzJkYy1iOTQ1LTlhM2NjMjQyYjRmZiIsIm1ldGEiOnsiaW50ZXJhY3Rpb25UeXBlIjoicmVkaXJlY3QifX0%3D%7C%7B%22service%22%3A%2200000041-0000-8888-8000-000000000000%22%2C%22isLegacyDomain%22%3Afalse%2C%22accessMapping%22%3A%22PublicAccessMapping%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22redirect%22%7D&session_state=bc769a45-7a91-472f-9a09-2693fef623d1
Please assist my problem in accordance with the above details.

It's worth reaching out to Azure support.

You need to make sure correct type(domain) account used to access DevOps, please check the details below, let me know if you have any queries, thanks.


I accessed Azure DevOps using the same account, but when I switched to the default directory, the page opened with the following link and only displays a blank screen.

There are different types for azure account: MS account, worker account or school account. They could use same email address. When you access DevOps, the sign in screen looks up the account type for you, you need to make sure correct account is used to access.  Please refer to the link for the details.

To access the DevOps for you, you can follow below steps:

Launch an Inprivate/Incognito browser window, access profile page: https://aex.dev.azure.com/me?.

On the left side, switch the domain, on the right side, it will show the DevOps organizations you have.




Make sure the target organization is listed on the right side, click the organization link, it will open the DevOps page.

